# Print all content of Widget to PDF (even elements of scroll area)

Tags: qt

I want to print multiple pages from Qt through PDF file. So I created a simple project to try it but this is just printing the shown elements without the items inside the scroll area...

Code:

```
QStringList HorizontalHeader;
    QStringList VerticalHeader;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        HorizontalHeader.append("This is a");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        VerticalHeader.append("This is a");
    }

    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(30);
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(5);
    ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(HorizontalHeader);
    ui->tableWidget->setVerticalHeaderLabels(VerticalHeader);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 30; j++){
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(j, i, new QTableWidgetItem("simple test"));
        }
    }

    int Wid = ui->tableWidget->width();
    int Hei = ui->tableWidget->height();

    QPrinter printer_pixmap(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer_pixmap.setPageSize (QPrinter :: A4); // Set the paper size to A4
    printer_pixmap.setOutputFormat (QPrinter :: PdfFormat); // Set the output format to pdf
    printer_pixmap.setOutputFileName ("C:/Users/Maroun Awad/Desktop/PDFGen.pdf"); // Set output path
    QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap :: grabWidget (this, this->rect()); // Get the picture of the interface

    QPainter painter_pixmap;
    painter_pixmap.begin(&printer_pixmap);
    QRect rect = painter_pixmap.viewport();
    int multiple = rect.width()/pixmap.width();
    painter_pixmap.scale (multiple, multiple); // Enlarge the image (all things to be drawn) multiple-1 times on the pdf
    painter_pixmap.drawPixmap (0, 0, pixmap); // painting
    painter_pixmap.end();
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you write

```
 QPixmap   pixmap = QPixmap::grabWidget(this, this->rect());
```

Actually in this case you create a screenshot from the window and save it as pdf. You need a text file that saves your data and then converts it to pdf.

And if you want that data with its Table shows in pdf file, I recommended use a HTML File and save Data in HTML and then convert it into pdf.

See [This Text Edit Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-textedit-example.html), it may help you.